# Azure Scheduler - Failed to generate SAS for 'xxx'

Tags: azure, scheduler, preview

I've started using the Azure Scheduler as a way to schedule background processing. At first it worked great, but all of a sudden I am no longer able to create jobs.

After clicking the "Generate SAS token" button I get the generic error "Failed to generate SAS for 'schedule'".

This was working 2 nights ago.

Any ideas on what to try?

[image: Failed to generate SAS for 'xxx']

Comment: In the meantime I've got around the issue by creating a second queue and updating my worker process to read the alternate queue. The first queue is dead to me.

Comment: Well, this is just an unfortunate incident. A similar incident happened with me a while ago with Service Bus Queues. Anyways, if you want a scheduler service, which does something for you at a particular    time, you can make use of Azure Timer Service available at https://github.com/kunaal2809/Azure-Timer-Service. You can keep it in your worker role and have a different partition key for different scheduled jobs.